# How to change HTML element's text and don't remove children in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using following code for translation elements with `data-i18next` attribute:

```
const elementsToTranslate = document.querySelectorAll('[data-i18next]');
for (let i = 0; i < elementsToTranslate.length; i++) {
    elementsToTranslate[i].innerText = i18next.t(elementsToTranslate[i].getAttribute('data-i18next'));
}
```

But it replaces all child elements.

I have h1 element with span child:

```
<h1 data-i18next="header-title" class="header__title">
    <span data-i18next="header__subtitle" class="header__subtitle"></span>
</h1>
```

After running translation function it becomes:

```
<h1 data-i18next="header-title" class="header__title">translated-text</h1>
```

But I need child items to stay. Without jquery.

Result I need:

```
<h1 data-i18next="header-title">translated-title
    <span data-i18next="header__subtitle">translated-span</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Where would the translated text go if there are other elements beside the text?

Comment: my suggestion is don't put the subtitle inside of the title element

Comment: This logic seems strange, why would you have a translation entry for `header-title` if the actual text you want to translate is inside `header__subtitle` - From what you have shown us `data-i18next` does not need to be on the `h1` element and should only exist on the `span` in this scenario. This also means your source text should have a matching entry for `header__subtitle` and not `header-title` - The fact you distinguish between subtitle and title in the DOM but not in the translated text source indicates a logical bug IMHO. Or, give the span the value of `header-title` and remove from `h1`

Comment: I would recommend textContent instead of innerText.

Comment: updated. I want to translate both: title and span inside it.

Comment: @caesay subtitle is span and it's better to put it inside

Comment: @Lain it didnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a textnode and prepend it in the element. This should end up in the result you seek according to your edit.

The function i18next.t() is not known, since you did not provide it. Thus I replace it with the attribute text for now.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            //Scope for the little translator and the list of textnodes
            ;(function(ns){
                'use strict';

                var _List = []; //Stores the created textnodes

                //Removes the textnodes from the List
                function _removeNodes(){
                    if(_List && _List.length){
                        for(var i=_List.length-1; i>=0; i--){
                            _List[i].parentNode && _List[i].parentNode.removeChild(_List[i])
                        };

                        _List = []
                    }
                };

                ns.Translator = {
                    Translate: function(){
                        _removeNodes();

                        const elementsToTranslate = document.querySelectorAll('[data-i18next]');
                        for (let i = 0; i < elementsToTranslate.length; i++){
                            var tE = elementsToTranslate[i];
                            var tText = tE.getAttribute('data-i18next'); //i18next.t(tE.getAttribute('data-i18next'));
                            var tN = document.createTextNode(tText);

                            _List.push(tN); //The node gets stored, so it can be removed again later

                            tE.insertBefore(tN, tE.firstChild)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }(window._ = window._ || {}));

            window.onload = function(){
                _.Translator.Translate()
                _.Translator.Translate()
                _.Translator.Translate()
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 data-i18next="header-title" class="header__title">
            <span data-i18next="header__subtitle" class="header__subtitle"></span>
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Result:

```
<h1 data-i18next="header-title" class="header__title">header-title
    <span data-i18next="header__subtitle" class="header__subtitle">header__subtitle</span>
</h1>
```

> updated. I want to translate both: title and span inside it.
>
> @caesay subtitle is span and it's better to put it inside

Comment: it works but when calling this function multiple times it inserts text node again

Comment: Yes, naturally. You could add a tE.removeAttribute('data-i18next') to avoid this unless you are using the attribute for other things.

Comment: I mean if user wants to change lang this function is called. And can be called multiple times. If I remove attribute translations will not work anymore.

Comment: Found solution. Need to remove text nodes of the tE recursively before insertion.

Comment: Yes that could work, does not have to tho, since not all textnodes need to be translations - could be other stuff. I updated my solution with a working alternative.